# Event trigger in verdor package

Tags: laravel-5.1

How do I override vendor package method to place my event trigger there? I would like to register an event for a vendor package method. How should I do that?

Let say user registered event. I researched in web, i saw some got using auth.login hook, but that is because the login package itself been fire that event, we just create the listener part.

Comment: are you able to edit the vendor package? If you are the package's developer just call `\Event::fire('my.event')`

Comment: @manix that not my package. So better not to touch it. So I would like to override it or any other method?